# Visual Studio Professional 2015 не видит код dll при профилировании

Tags: visual-studio, профилирование

Пытаюсь найти узкие места в dll, написанных мною же. Запускаю профилирование (инструментирование), указываю проект, использующий dll, проекты самих dll. В отчете нет вызовов функций, содержащихся в dll, только те, что в проекте вызывающем dll.

Comment: А сами dll-файлы у вас из отладочной сборки используются?

Comment: Они подключены как проекты. Но в разделе "Ссылки" отладочной сборки есть пути к dllкам

Comment: А по этим путям отладочные сборки лежат или нет?

Comment: ссылки на bin/debug/*.dll, там все есть

Comment: Исполняемый файл о проекте ничего не знает, он просто загружает DLL. Отсюда и возникает вопрос: какие же сборки он загружает?

Comment: Как можно посмотреть какие сборки загружаются?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Просто переподключил все ссылки еще раз.